# Dynamic table using parameter or variable in table name cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am creating a dynamic table using `mysql` query table name should be unique that's why i have added user id to table name.
In Controller:

```
$last_id = $this->User->getLastInsertID();

//$table_name = 'hello_'.$last_id.'_tutors';
// debug($table_name);

$this->User->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_`.$last_id.`_tutors` (
      `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `tutor_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `tutor_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `tutor_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `tutor_gender` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `tutor_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `area_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `matric` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `inter` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `graduation` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `masters` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `diploma` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `other_education` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=67 ;
 ");
```

it gave syntax error like:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '.75.`_tutors` ( `tutor_name`
>   varchar(50) NOT NULL, `tutor_email` var' at line 1

if anyone may help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$this->User->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_".$last_id."_tutors` (
```

Comment: my reputation must be 15.